# twisted prematurely closing connection with java socket

Tags: java, android, python, sockets, twisted

i have the following server code:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.protocols.basic import NetstringReceiver

class Echo(NetstringReceiver):

    def stringReceived(self, request):
        print("stringReceived: %s" % request)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print(reason)
```

this python client will repeatedly cause the server to print stringReceived: ... messages as expected with a single connection:

```
import socket
import json
import sys
import time

HOST = 'localhost'    # The remote host
PORT = 6001              # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
params = {
    "chat_id": sys.argv[1],
    "session": sys.argv[2],
}
send = '%s:%s,' % (len(json.dumps(params)), json.dumps(params))
s.send((send.strip()))
while 1:
    params = {
        "chat_id": sys.argv[1],
        "session": sys.argv[2],
        "message": sys.argv[3],
    }
    send = '%s:%s,' % (len(json.dumps(params)), json.dumps(params))
    s.send(send)
    time.sleep(1)
```

this java code, however, will output stringReceived: ... once. after that single output, i get the error,

> [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): : Connection was closed
>   cleanly.

the java socket code is:

```
   public void sendMessage(final String message)
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if(socket == null) {
                        socket = new Socket("192.168.1.6", 6001);
                        Log.i("", "CREATING:"+socket.toString());
                    }
                    Log.i("", socket.toString());
                    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
                    output.println(String.format("%d:%s,", message.length(), message));
                    output.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i("exc", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

what is it that is closing the connection prematurely? this is the only class that has access to that socket and this is the only method that uses it.

Comment: maybe due to a firewall?

Comment: the server initially accepts data then closes. a firewall would have outright blocked the connection, correct?

Comment: have you tried with a telnet connection (say from your PC)?

Comment: yes, i can telnet to it when it's running from a machine outside the network altogether.

Answer (score 2):

after days of banging my head against the wall, i figured it out.

the NetstringReceiver requires input to be this format:

`3:lol,`

or

`12:hello world!,`

if the input does not conform to the netstring convention, the connection is lost.

so what was wrong with my code?

```
output.println(String.format("%d:%s,", message.length(), message));
```

the println was adding a newline character to the messages going out, breaking the convention and then losing the connection. changing this to `print` solved my problem.